# ImportError: cannot import name views while running the server

Tags: django, python-2.7

I am getting following error and don´t know how to solve this:

> from . import views
>
> ImportError: cannot import name views

This are my scripts i am using:

**urls.py**

```
from django.conf.urls import url

from django.contrib import admin

from . import views

urlpatterns = [

    url(r'^$',views.home,name='index'),
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),]
```

**views.py**

```
from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):

    return HttpResponse("libaray management system")
```

Comment: Can you show your project directory structure?

Comment: Your question cannot be properly answered without your directory structure. Just note that if `urls.py` is the root url and `views` is within an app, then you have to use Headmaster's solution - relative imports ("from . import XXX") are for intra-packages imports (cf the comments on Headmaster's answer).

Answer (score 1):

Try to import like this

```
from your_app_name import views
```

I can't say, what is your project structure and where are your views.py and urls.py files. My guess, that you have some problems with how you import (check the absolute and relative import in python). In that case you can use import style from above code example.

Comment: the op's syntax is perfectly legal and (as far as we can tell at least) correctly used.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers - how you can tell this, if you don't know the project structure?

Comment: If that's the project level urls - which it seems to be, given that it includes admin - there is almost certainly no views.py at that level, so this answer seems correct.

Comment: @Headmaster that's why I wrote "as far as we can tell at least" and voted to close the question for lacking a MCVE.

Comment: @DanielRoseman well spotted and you're probably right (but that's still an assumption). But just stating "you should ..." _without any explanation_ (ie "if this is your root urlconf then...") is still a wrong answer IMHO since the syntax itself is legal and would be correct in the app's urls.py.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers - And I, instead of voting and complaining, just tried to help the user

Comment: @Headmaster that's where we disagree. You think your answer is helpful, I think it's not because it doesn't explain _why_ you think he "should import like this". Even if the proposed solution actually works, neither the OP nor anyone reading this answer will understand why this solves the problem, so you're actually encouraging cargo-cult  programming...

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers - hm, interesting opinion. Maybe, you are right, it's better to give some explanations. I will update my answer